# looking for stereo vision howto with 2 USB webcams

Tags: ros, stereo-camera, webcam, ros-groovy, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I want to experiment with stereo vision in ROS Groovy using two USB webcams. I found the stereo_image_proc package with the [ChoosingGoodStereoParameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters) tutorial. Unfortunately, it seems to be written to an older ROS version, and it doesn't work. There is an example [bag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=rotating_detergent.bag) file that should be used for the tutorial, but the images in the bag file can neither be seen in the rxbag nor in the imageview. Rxbag shows the timelines but no images. Imageview shows only empty windows, no images. I don't know why isn't it working and how could I make it work. Is there somewhere a working tutorial on stereo vision for ROS or can anyone explain how to use 2 webcams for stereo vision?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62602/looking-for-stereo-vision-howto-with-2-usb-webcams/) by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am following this

http://ohmm.wikidot.com/minoru

they are using the umd_ros_pkg stack

according to the ros wiki this package is considered unstable

but i think the umd stack uses the following package for stereo
http://www.ros.org/wiki/uvc_stereo?distro=fuerte

which i believe is stable

---

Originally posted by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) with karma: 418 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-14**:
Thanks @Sential_Bias! I wanted to make it work with the usb_cam drivers, and now I managed to, but I am also going to check out the uvc_stereo solution, thanks for sharing!

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-15**:
I am trying to make it work by following the page you sent, but it crashes all the time. I modified the launch file and I also created the example.yaml files. Can you share your launch files? It seems my cameras aren't compatible with the uvc_camera driver.

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-05-16**:
Hi which node crashes? Could you post the error message ?